# Inspecting web pages that run on mobile devices

Tags: ios, windows, blackberry

In any conventional web browser we can right click a html page and see "view page source" to see the underlying HTML,but is the same possible with  mobile applications. Is there any way to do it?

Comment: This is a question more suited to SuperUser.com

Comment: Not really; it's more suited to IRC.